# How to setup environment variables for AWS S3 in angular?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have the access key id and secret access key for AWS S3 bucket and in development i have these in environment file but in production it is not working.

in development:

```
export const environment = {
    aws: {
        region: 'ap-south-1',
        accessKeyId: '??',
        secretAccessKey: '??',
    }
}
```

now in production I read that I need to do the following in terminal (vcode):

```
setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
setx AWS_DEFAULT_REGION us-west-2
```

then I tried to deploy to render.com but still not working!